# CS GO competitive match making

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

I can't connect to a competitive match with people on my friends list, but I can play by myself. It's happening on both my accounts, I can enter a lobby click go and it works but then when it says "confirming match" it says "[My username] failed to accept", or my friend failed to accept, when there was no Accept button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes CSGO seems to think you are not logged into steam. The only way i fixed this happening to me when it happens was to have every party in the lobby completely close steam, reconnect and then re-open the game and then it was usually ok.

Another time this has happened was a problem with steams servers experiencing above expected traffic. Eventually as servers calmed down it functioned agian.

Comment: Restarting the game usually does this (no need to close Steam), unless you're *also* offline from the Steam community.

Comment: I have never had that work for me... I had to completely close and reconect to steam before it would allow me but maybe it works for somev then I guess :)